# difference between cookie and string in request header

Tags: java, cookies

Cookie is nothing but a small piece of information most of the times a string in the request header send by the client to server. If i add one more string to the request header at server in java like   `conn.addRequestProperty("iPlanetDirectoryPro", token);` then is there any difference between the two? Can the second one be also considered as a cookie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to read the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) (message headers) and [the HTTP State Management specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).

The HTTP specification provides message headers

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the
> field value.

For example, you could have

```
Content-Length:42
```

This is a header.

The HTTP State Management specification defines the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers. Those are two specific headers that are used for achieving state in HTTP request and response cycles (HTTP is a stateless protocol).

So

> conn.addRequestProperty("iPlanetDirectoryPro", token); then is there
> any difference between the two?

Yes, there is a big difference. The above is a simple request header. It has nothing to do with a `Cookie`.

Comment: so just to clarify, cookie is just a header but a special one at that. Therefore cookie is just a special header which can allow for state.

Comment: @theprogrammer Sure, you can think of it that way. It's special in the same way that `Content-Length` is special in that it's included in the specification(s).