# How to send cookies over URL connection

Tags: java, cookies, urlconnection

I am trying to set Cookies and request headers via URL connection. Here is the client side code

```
UUID = request.getHeader("UUID");               
conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", iPlanetDirectoryPro);
conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
objOstr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
objOstr.write(res);
```

One server side i am trying a retrieve the cookie using "iPlanetDirectoryPro" as the cookie name. But i am getting null. What is the mistake i am doing here?

If i set as   conn.addRequestProperty("iPlanetDirectoryPro", iPlanetDirectoryPro);  then what is the difference between cookie-and-string-in-request-header `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226475/difference-between-cookie-and-string-in-request-header`

Comment: So change the server side code as stated in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
  conn.getRequestProperty("Cookies");
```

See the [doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getRequestProperty(java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi, The problem is with the server side code, I cannot change it. they will try to receive with same name. Its my job to send with iPlanetDirectoryPro as the cookie name.  Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: See my friend you are adding cookie like this conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", iPlanetDirectoryPro); so retrieving should be like the above answer. What key you are passing to requestProperty that key only should be used to get that request property.

Comment: Here iPlanetDirectoryPro is not cookie name but its a cookie.Please see the docs.

Comment: Tell me how you are retrieving at server side and where you are getting cookie as null?

Comment: HI one server side they are receiving as coon.getRequestProperty("iPlanetDirectoryPro")

Comment: If i set as conn.addRequestProperty("iPlanetDirectoryPro", iPlanetDirectoryPro); will this be a cookie

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45635/discussion-between-maclean-pinto-and-shoaib-chikate)

Comment: So you will always get null bcoz here in Map of RequestProperties there is no such key ("iPlanetDirectoryPro"). So either change at client to ("iPlanetDirectoryPro") which as not good as we have standard name as Cookie and it will be consider string-in-request-header as or change to server side conn.getProperty("Cookies") which as answer I have written above.